# Diagnose brightness control

Tags: troubleshooting, brightness, bug-reporting, vga

Brightness control on my laptop does not work, how can I diagnose if it's unsupported, or a bug? And if it is a bug, what do I include in the bug report?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for all the responses, specially @Guandalino for the bounty. But unfortunately the laptop in question is no longer functional due to an accident involving water. And as such I cannot actively participate and try the out the potential solutions.

Those still interested in this question, please participate in this discussion at [Ask Ubuntu Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1532/question-i-can-no-longer-respond-to).

Comment: This is a very smart question, I'm going to start a bounty for this. Thanks

Comment: I have closed this as it's no longer possible to answer it. If you feel you have a similar issue, please feel free to start your own question but when you do, please make sure you include what hardware (make and model) you're talking about as laptop bugs are usually extremely hardware specific.

Comment: @Guandalino I have refunded your bounty.

Answer (score 4):

There is a step-by-step troubleshooting guide [on the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

Check or dig around your laptop vendors website to see if they have any useful information relating dianosing the control.

If the vendor has forum, try seek information there also. Please add your laptop model detail as part of the post so we know which product and model you are seeking support on.

Comment: Just asking how to troubleshoot - not that it matters now; check the updated question.

Comment: @Oxwivi I have updated the post. I know it does not matter now but like  `Guandalin` said, this is a very smart question and thought I add information which might aid someone looking for something similar in the future. Thanks for raising the flag.

Comment: I was referring to you asking for laptop details.